# how can i call web services with curl with json param?

Tags: java, json, web-services, curl

I'm programming in Java.
I developed a test web service in which I pass a random json and the service returns me hello

Here the web service code:

```
@Path("test")
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String test(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @QueryParam("array")String array)
{
    return "hello";
}
```

I call the service with curl

```
curl -v -H 'token:aaaa' 'http://140.145.1.2/clayapi/restservices/test?array=[{"name":"george","lastname":"ronney"}]';
```

message of error:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 60
```

I tried to add -g but it doesn't work .. how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`-G`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) along with [`--data-urlencode`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode):

```bash
curl -v -G 'http://example.org' \
    -H 'header:value' \
    --data-urlencode 'array=[{"name":"george","lastname":"ronney"}]'
```

From the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> ### `-G`, `--get`
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with `-d`, `--data`, `--data-binary` or `--data-urlencode` to be used in an HTTP `GET` request instead of the `POST` request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a `?` separator. [...]

> ### `--data-urlencode <data>`
>
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other `-d`, `--data` options with the exception that this performs URL-encoding. [...]